# Kalanchoe - thin leaves and white spots

Tags: diagnosis, houseplants

This Kalanchoe has been losing leaves for a while now, the existing ones seem thin and white spots have appeared. I have repotted it recently and it has shown signs of improvement, but it still does not look well.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]